# Advanced QCompleter

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, nokia

Well, i was looking on [QCompleter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qcompleter.html), it's pretty cool of what i can see. But i looked on Visual Studio 2010 that when you do for example: MessageBox(HWND hWnd, it shows a rectangle (white background, black text) that shows MessageBox(**HWND hWnd**, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UNIT uType); What i mean it's highlights the position you are.
Here is an image:
[image: Image showing example]

Answer (score 2):

Other than using `setCompletionMode` to one of three enum options it's quite possible you can't achieve this without subclassing it and implementing your own version. `QCompleter` is a model parser so it's more akin to what visual studio does when you type `.` or `->` and pick an available method/member/etc on the current object.